# Will Android system send broadcast to tell that it can not open a file?

Tags: android, broadcast

I download a file and send a notification to notification bar. When the user clicks it, the system will open the file. But sometimes, there's no application for the downloaded file to open it, so I want to toast a message to user to tell them the file can not opened.

I want to know is there a broadcast sent by Android system to tell me that can not open the 
file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see from your question, you want to toast a message when NotFoundActivityException occurs. So, you can do the code as follow :

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    File file = new File(your_file_full_path); 
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), your_file_content_type);
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(activity_context, "Activity not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```